# store image from firebase storage to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

am working on an instagram clone and need assistance with a READ: functionality.

okay,so i managed to upload an image to firebase storage using an upload button (from a div in html) and it stores the image in my firebase storage bucket and gives me a access token (which I believe is the url). so I believe the upload function is working.

I created a firestore database and linked it to my app successfully.Now I want to (1) when I upload an image to firebase storage,I need that image to be dynamically stored in firestore using the access token (URL). And (2) display that uploaded image on my UI together with username and caption.

'''

```
            <div class="upload">
              <button class="post-button">Upload</button>
            </div>

<!-- UPLOAD CONTAINER DIV -->

<div class="post-container">
  <div class="upload-file">
    Upload Files<br />
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple /><br /><br />
    <button id="send">Post</button>
    <p id="uploading"></p>
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="progress"></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

// FIREBASE STORAGE CODE

```
var files = [];
document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  files = e.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i]);
  }
});

document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", function () {
  //checks if files are selected
  if (files.length != 0) {
    //Loops through all the selected files
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      //create a storage reference
      var storage = firebase.storage().ref(files[i].name);

      //upload file
      var upload = storage.put(files[i]);

      //update progress bar
      upload.on(
        "state_changed",
        function progress(snapshot) {
          var percentage =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          document.getElementById("progress").value = percentage;
        },

        function error() {
          alert("error uploading file");
        },

        function complete() {
          document.getElementById(
            "uploading"
          ).innerHTML += `${files[i].name} upoaded <br />`;
        }
      );
    }
  } else {
    alert("No file chosen");
  }
});

function getFileUrl(filename) {
  //create a storage reference
  var storage = firebase.storage().ref(filename);

  //get file url
  storage
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(function (url) {
      console.log(url);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error encountered");
    });
}
```

'''

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What is keeping you from [writing to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in the code where you now have `console.log(url);`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write to firestore, I've been drowning in documentations etc with no success. Thing is am still new to coding with 5 months experience so I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: That's a completely valid state to be in, and I am excited that you're joining the worldwide community of developers. But in order to be able to help you here on Stack Overflow, we need to have a more concrete question than what you posted so far. What happened when you tried to write to Firestore in the place where you now log the URL? Was there an error message?